# TeamCity IntelliJ Inspections - Include Files in Inspection Scope

Tags: intellij-idea, continuous-integration, teamcity, static-analysis, code-inspection

### Question: How can I get TeamCity to run inspections against the 3 html files in the www root directory?

I'm working on a node.js project. The team are all using JetBrains IDEA based IDEs. We have shared our Inspection Profile and a Scope for them to run against.

We have just setup TeamCity and have a build configuration to run the Inspections. It is working identically for everything except the 3 html files directly under the "www" directory. The problem is that errors for those 3 files are reported in IntelliJ but not in TeamCity.

The only thing that appears to be different is the scope. IntelliJ uses scope defined in an xml file. TeamCity scope is set through the UI (build step form field "Include / exclude patterns"). TeamCity's scope syntax is different to IntelliJ's ...for the life of me I cannot get TeamCity to operate on the same scope!

#### Intended Scope

[Here is a picture of the Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrwDr.png) with the inspection scope underlined in green. We want to exclude libraries and the very root folder of config, but include everything else (i.e. everything we write).

#### TeamCity Scope

I have tried 2 strategies and both seem to work in IntelliJ and fail on TeamCity.

Attempt 1 - Include Only:

```
+:backend/**
+:tests/**
+:www/css/**
+:www/dist/**
+:www/images/**
+:www/*
```

Attempt 2 - Include entire www then Exclude:

```
+:backend/**
+:tests/**
+:www/**
-:www/components/**
-:www/components-unmanaged/**
-:www/data/**
-:www/images/**
```

#### IntelliJ Scope

In IntelliJ both work.

Attempt 1 - Include Only:

```
pattern="file:backend//*||file:tests//*||file:www/css//*||file:www/dist//*||file:www/images//*||file:www/index.html||file:www/loadsave.html||file:www/logical.html"

...more readable with some line breaks:

file:backend//*
||file:tests//*
||file:www/css//*
||file:www/dist//*
||file:www/images//*
||file:www/index.html
||file:www/loadsave.html
||file:www/logical.html
```

Attempt 2 - Include entire www then Exclude:

```
(file:backend//*||file:tests//*||file:www//*)&amp;&amp;!file:www/components//*&amp;&amp;!file:www/components-unmanaged//*&amp;&amp;!file:www/data//*&amp;&amp;!file:www/images//

...again, more readable with line breaks:

(
file:backend//*
||file:tests//*
||file:www//*
)
&&!file:www/components//*
&&!file:www/components-unmanaged//*
&&!file:www/data//*
&&!file:www/images//
```

#### References

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Inspections#Inspections-IdeaPatterns

> the pattern must satisfy the following rules: must end with either **
>   or * (this effectively limits the patterns to only the directories
>   level, they do not support file-level patterns);
>
> ...
>
> the include pattern has a special behavior (due to underlying
>   limitations): it includes the directory specified and all the files
>   residing directly in the directories above the one specified.

#### Other Thoughts: Differing Inspection Support

The only other thought I had was that perhaps TeamCity just plain doesn't support the HTML inspections category that IntelliJ does, or so some bizarre reason it refuses to assess .html files.

#### Software Versions

- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2 (Build #IU-145.972, built on May 14, 2016)
- TeamCity Professional 9.1.7 (build 37573)

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work for HTML files? What exactly does not work?
Please note that at the moment inspections highlighting is not supported for HTML files in TeamCity, please vote for the request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21807.

Comment: I mean I am trying to run the same inspections on the same scope in IntelliJ and on TeamCity. At the moment the entire discrepancy lies within 3 .html files that are at the root of the www directory.

_Edit: to clarify, "what does not work" is that the inspection errors I am seeing in IntelliJ on those files are not shown in TeamCity. They appear to not be being run._

Comment: So you're telling me that it's not a scope issue, but that HTML inspections do not exist for TeamCity? I can fairly confidently assert that TeamCity is providing JavaScript inspections (in contradiction to that link). I can see the vast majority of my errors.